# How to pass filter parameters in a URL in Python

Tags: python

I have below to send as URL parameter `(params = para1)`

```
para1 = (
        ('filter', 'local_ip: \'10.10.10.10\''),  
        )
```

I want to send a variable for the local IP taken from a for loop. But the syntax keep coming as a "`message`": "`Invalid filter expression supplied`"

## Code is like below

```
for k in ip1:
    if ip1 != None:
        para1 = (
                ('filter', 'local_ip: k'), 
          #     ('filter', 'local_ip: \'10.101.168.21\''),  # working when its like this.
                )
        print(para1)
        re2 = requests.get('https://api.example.com/devices/queries/devices/v1', headers=headers2, params=para1)
```

Can anybody help me to write the correct filtering command?

Answer (score 0):

You've forgotten to escape another quote there: `'local_ip: \'k''` -> `'local_ip: \'k\''`

It's useful to keep in mind that you can enclose strings in either `'` or `"` quotes, so if you need to use `'` inside your string, enclose the whole string into `"` to avoid messy escaping:

EDIT:

```
para1 = (
          ('filter', f"local_ip: '{k.rstrip()}'"), 
)
```

Notice `f` before the string begins, and `{}` between which you can write any Python expression, and its value will be substituted in the string. `.rstrip()` function deletes all space characters (blanks, newlines) from the riht end of a string.

Comment: Sorry I have made mistake in the question

` para1 = (
               ('filter', 'local_ip: \'10.101.168.21\''),  # working when its like this.
                )
`
Code is working properly when I send the IP address like above

So I want to send K value taken from the for loop. I think String format not working.

Comment: What does `k` hold? A string of IP or some Python object from a library? Maybe `f"local_ip: '{str(k)}'"` would work for you

Comment: k is a filtered element from for loop. it's a string. When I used this way ('filter', f"local_ip: '{k}'"), error mgs "code": 400,\n   "message": "invalid IP address for local_ip: 10.96.248.10\\n"\n

Comment: As per to above how para1 output
(('filter', "local_ip: '10.137.191.29\n'"),)

when manual IP input
(('filter', "local_ip: '10.101.168.21'"),)
only difference is \n

Comment: To remove `\n` from `k` you can  `f"local_ip: '{k.rstrip()}'"`